# IIS SSL with Multiple Sites and 1 IP

Tags: ssl, iis

I have these sites:
app.example.com
api.example.com
staff.example.com
www.example.com / example.com

I used `LetsEncrypt` to generate free `SSLs` for each of the sites. Things seem to be fine except it seems that only one `SSL cert` is being served for all of the sites! I even removed and manually readded the `SSL bindings` to each of the sites and still had the same problem. I ended up removing all of the `SSL certs` except my API one and removed all of the `SSL bindings` except for the API `Web Site`, and bizarrely, I can still load the other sites as `HTTPS` even though I removed the `SSL bindings` for those `Web Sites` (the remaining `SSL cert` is of course showing for all of the sites still)! Wth? I thought you need the `443/SSL Bindings` in order to even browse that site via `https`! I can confirm that these are all individual `Web Sites`, not `Virtual Apps` inside of a single `Web Site`. What am I missing? How can I get `IIS` to serv up the right `cert` for the right `Web Site`? This is a `Azure VM` running `Win Server 2012 R2`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

From the IIS management interface, you can select each web site, and `Edit Bindings...`.

In the pop-up window, select the `https` site and the `Edit...` button. Fill in the `Host name:` field with the specific website host name, check the `Require Server Name Indication` and select the specific ceritificate to use for that site in the `SSL certificate` dropdown.

This will allow you to host multiple secure sites on the same server. It is an improvement introduced in IIS v.8

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find it. Maybe a moderator can chip in and provide a link

Comment: I had the exact same setup done on a web server not 15 minutes ago, works as advertised. this saved me a ton of work (adding extra IPs/NICs to my server for extra SSL binding)

Comment: All of my sites have that turned on and it is still having this problem.

Comment: could these questions help? * [wrong certificate served](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866117/the-incorrect-localhost-certificate-is-being-served-by-iis) and [who is serving the certificate](http://serverfault.com/questions/611531/how-do-i-determine-where-an-ssl-certificate-is-being-served-from)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a certificate that has all those names as subject names or a wildcard certificate. So, single certificate will be used for all of them. After that, you can configure each website with that certificate and SNI.

Comment: I realize that's an option but I don't think that LetsEncrypt has an option for wildcard domains