# IIS keeps using the old certificate after new one has been selected

Tags: windows, ssl, iis-10, windows-server-2022

I have had an LetsEncrypt certificate generated through Win-Acme on an IIS website. After some time, it was requested to be changed for a different certificate, generated by RapidSSL. I have received the certificate, successfully installed it into IIS and selected it in the site's bindings. IIS, however, still keeps using the old certificate and ignores the new one.

### Things I have tried:

- Removing the certificate from IIS and from Certificate storage
- Restarting the IIS Site
- Restarting all related Application pools
- Setting the `Idle timeout` of all related application pools to 1 minute and letting them all terminate - as specified in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/win-acme/win-acme/issues/262)
- Restarted the entire Windows server
- Removed the certificate manually using `netsh http delete sslcert`, according to command output it was successfully deleted (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521040/iis-using-the-old-ssl-not-the-new-ssl)), after that re-added the certificate in IIS bindings
- Removed scheduled renewal from Win-Acme

IIS, however, somehow seems to still have it cached and returns it.

### Noteworthy things:

- The old certificate was still valid, i never had any issues replacing an expired certificate
- There is no loadbalancer or proxy
- I have always used OpenSSL CLI tool to check for the certificate, in case my browser was caching it

### Issue from Server Name Indication (SNI)?

I have done a little research and stumbled upon this [answer from Lex Li on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290690/why-would-iismanager-bindings-dialog-show-a-different-certificate-than-netsh-ht) and [this blogpost](https://github.com/RickStrahl/BlogPosts/blob/master/2016-05/IIS%20Serving%20the%20Wrong%20SSL%20Certificate/IIS%20Serving%20the%20Wrong%20SSL%20Certificate.md), where there is explained, that this issue may actually originate from Server Name Indication. I did however verify, that all sites run on `All Unassigned` IP address and that all of the SSL bindings have SNI enabled - both in IIS GUI and `Hostname:port` on `netsh http show sslcert`. Also, when i try to run OpenSSL CLI tool with `-servername` parameter (which should, as I learned [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1012750/1053723), make the check in regards to SNI), it still returns the old certificate:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect my.example.com:443 -servername my.example.com
```

If I, however, try re-adding the binding, after viewing the certificate with `netsh`, however, the **correct certificate** appears. It seems to match the description of issues with SNI linked above, however, none of the resolutions in those posts work for me.

I'm really starting to become puzzled by this - any idea on how to progress further? Thanks!

Comment: Try restarting the server.

Comment: Yes, I have tried restarting both the IIS Webserver as well as the entire Windows server after the steps above. Sadly to no success.

Comment: Does the application have its own cache maybe?? Somewhere in a directory

Comment: Are you testing with a web browser  or looking at the certificate directly with a tool such as (the real) `wget` or `openssl s_client`? Some web browsers (I'm looking at you, Google Chrome) cache the certificate for an indeterminate period of time and do not notice that you've updated it on the server.

Comment: Couldn't leave comments earlier, I was asking if you've tried checking the site configuration via %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config or via configuration editor within IIS?